# javascript xmlhttprequest Authorization magento oauth

Tags: javascript, magento, oauth

I'm cant understand how to user authorization headers in vanila javascript.

guide magento rest-api (oAuth 1.0),
https://github.com/nickvane/Magento-RestApi/wiki/Authentication-steps.

how i implement this headers in my code:
POST /oauth/initiate

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888",oauth_consumer_key="YOUR-CONSUMER-KEY",oauth_nonce="t02auly6elcuthly",oauth_signature="7FMe1UducbDUgCJWQY4Avv3g3f4%3D",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1371098086",oauth_version="1.0"
```

my code:

```
var ajax = new XMLHTTPREQUEST();
    ajax.open('POST', myurl+'/oauth/initiate',true);
    ajax.send();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if(ajax.readyState == 4 ){

             console.log(ajax.responseText);
          }
    }
```

how i can add headers like this to my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about set request header: [XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader)

```
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader(header, value)
```

you can use XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader API to set header for any request.

For OAuth you can read more: [OAuth](https://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Auth-Flow.html).

In your case to implement OAuth to get the token

POST /oauth/initiate

The following request parameters should be present in the Authorization header:

```
oauth_callback - an URI to which the Service Provider will redirect the resource owner (user) after the authorization is complete.
oauth_consumer_key - the Consumer Key value, retrieved after the registration of the application.
oauth_nonce - a random value, uniquely generated by the application.
oauth_signature_method - name of the signature method used to sign the request. Can have one of the following values: HMAC-SHA1, RSA-SHA1, and PLAINTEXT.
oauth_signature - a generated value (signature).
oauth_timestamp - a positive integer, expressed in the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT.
oauth_version - OAuth version.
```

Good Luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this:

```
ajax.setRequestHeader('Authorization','OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888",oauth_consumer_key="86a507bfc290e0cfa0e1813f555f1cb2",oauth_nonce="9c89f47ef962a69f7666a35e27d9e7da",oauth_signature="8lqJ6/hOPUeYFpKtuVGilg3lmew=",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1477181081",oauth_version="1.0"')
```